# Oddity with "\n" vs '\n'

Tags: ruby, string

I have been away from ruby for awhile and I noticed something very strange (at least to me) in 1.9.3. Perhaps someone can explain it to me.

I was trying to split a string into lines so i did `string.split('\n')`, but this was giving me hell.

Eventually I tracked down the problem to using single quotes instead of double quotes. That is `string.split("\n")`

In the process of tracking this down I noticed a few things

1. `'\n'.ord == 92`
2. `"\n".ord == 10`
3. `'\'.ord` is not valid ruby
4. `'\\'.ord == 92`

The only theory I have is that the single quotes cause ruby to not parse the string and thus treat `\n` as two characters. However, if this is the case why does `'\'` not pass the processor?

Am I missing something? Why doesn't split convert the string to the correct ascii?

P.S. Here is some test code to illustrate my point

```
"asdf\nasdf".split('\n').size #=> 1
"asdf\nasdf".split("\n").size #=> 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to xdazz's information, `'\'.ord` is syntactically incorrect because the backslash escapes the following single quote. Use `'\\'.ord` for that purpose instead.

Answer (score 6):

`'\n'` is a string contain 2 char `\` and `n`.

`"\n"` is a string contain 1 char, the new line char (LF) with ascii code `10`.

When you use double quote, `\` is used to escape special chars.

Comment: Additionally, in single-quoted strings the backslash is used only to escape single quotes, which is why `'\'.ord` is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @Fraxtil Ah, duh this makes sense. Thanks. Please make this an answer

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes do interpretation / processing within the string, thus `"\n"` is a newline while `'\n'` is a \ and an n.